# Xaml Grid with TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Good afternoon everyone,

I have a little problem that can seem easy but for what I have there is no solution yet.

I tried to provide information to make the solution as easy as possible to be understandable:

I have a Grid with 2 columns and 2 rows and I want to put a text in 3 of the 4 cases.

This is what I have for now:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
               In nec pharetra leo. Donec quis faucibus elit. 
               Praesent vel risus libero. 
               Curabitur neque urna, pulvinar eu imperdiet feugiat, molestie sit amet orci.
               Sed purus est, vehicula in tortor et, blandit dictum dolor.
               Etiam fringilla non purus sed vulputate.
               Maecenas id sagittis lorem, et ultricies massa.
               Nullam bibendum dolor vel ipsum cursus congue. 
               Quisque ac molestie mi. Etiam ac ex quam. 
               Fusce tempus eros nec ultrices condimentum. 
               Proin malesuada sem id suscipit vehicula. 
               Integer risus nibh, ultricies eget rhoncus sit amet, mattis id quam. 
               Mauris ac augue sit amet nulla scelerisque sollicitudin. 
               Duis ac nulla sem. Sed elementum ac tortor vel finibus.
               Ut magna diam, efficitur a cursus a, commodo ut risus.
               Mauris elementum nulla tortor, a egestas ipsum luctus et.
               Fusce quis dui purus.
               Donec aliquam fermentum diam vitae vulputate. 
               Donec at quam condimentum nunc efficitur consequat.
               Mauris id porttitor tortor.
               Nunc odio diam, ullamcorper id neque non, molestie volutpat elit. 
               Ut rutrum dignissim ex, et hendrerit massa tincidunt eget. "
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

</Grid>
```

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4pYL.jpg)

In the picture foregoing, i want to have the text in 3 of the 4 cases.
If you have any solution or workaround let me know.

Comment: Can you post a mockup / drawing of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Try using run element for formatting the sections of text individually.

Comment: With two TextBox maybe? One on the first row (both columns) and the other one on the second row, first column?

Comment: @Fred [link] (http://imgur.com/65bXE5K) something like that (made in paint) without the text being cut of course.

Comment: @Versatile / Kryptos I have a dynamic text inside a listview. I don't think divide the text in pieces would be good.

Comment: @Shrin if it is dynamic text then you can look at binding run elements accordingly to the properties that hold those values.
If there is any other meaning for dynamic text then let us know what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i work more on that and based on Johnathon response ( your link don't seem to be for winrt/windows phone) , I checked for WP equivalent and i get **Section** for WP 8.0 and **RichTextBlock** with **RichTextBlockOverflow** in winrt.

[Here is a great tutorial for that.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/windows-8-store-app-wrap-text-around-image506/)

I tried to implement it in my first example and this is what i have : [Grid v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhLgS.jpg)

And here's the code :

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RichTextBlock 
        x:Name="RtbSource"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=RtboFirst}"
        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
        TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
               In nec pharetra leo. Donec quis faucibus elit. 
               Praesent vel risus libero. 
               Curabitur neque urna, pulvinar eu imperdiet feugiat, molestie sit amet orci.
               Sed purus est, vehicula in tortor et, blandit dictum dolor.
               Etiam fringilla non purus sed vulputate.
               Maecenas id sagittis lorem, et ultricies massa.
               Nullam bibendum dolor vel ipsum cursus congue. 
               Quisque ac molestie mi. Etiam ac ex quam. 
               Fusce tempus eros nec ultrices condimentum. 
               Proin malesuada sem id suscipit vehicula. 
               Integer risus nibh, ultricies eget rhoncus sit amet, mattis id quam. 
               Mauris ac augue sit amet nulla scelerisque sollicitudin. 
               Duis ac nulla sem. Sed elementum ac tortor vel finibus.
               Ut magna diam, efficitur a cursus a, commodo ut risus.
               Mauris elementum nulla tortor, a egestas ipsum luctus et.
               Fusce quis dui purus.
               Donec aliquam fermentum diam vitae vulputate. 
               Donec at quam condimentum nunc efficitur consequat.
               Mauris id porttitor tortor.
               Nunc odio diam, ullamcorper id neque non, molestie volutpat elit. 
               Ut rutrum dignissim ex, et hendrerit massa tincidunt eget. "/>
        </Paragraph>

    </RichTextBlock>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow 
        x:Name="RtboFirst"
        Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

I'll try to implement it on my project , i'll upload any important information.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Flow Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx). They allow you to customize how the text in the document is layed out.

The lower right corner, (assuming that's the 4th case you don't want text) put a [BlockUIContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) in it. The container could be empty or hidden, not collapsed, so that layout is still applied. This forces the text to not encroach on the container.